# C++ pointer problem : How to fix bugs in these codes?

Tags: c++, vector, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <vector>
struct node{
    int x;
};
node* temp = new node();
std::vector<node*> ptrs;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    temp->x = i;
    ptrs.push_back(temp);
}
std::vector<node*>:: iterator j;
for (j = ptrs.begin(); j != ptrs.end(); j++){
    std::cout << (*j)->x;
}
delete temp;
```

This prints `999999999` as output. I want to have `123456789`.

What is the best way to modify this? I mean, what is the best fashion?

Comment: What are your bugs? What is happening that you don't want to happen? This looks like it won't compile? Include your compiler errors verbatim please!

Comment: Please edit your code to contain [mcve]

Comment: This prints 999999999 as output. I want to have 123456789

Comment: Hint: How many nodes have you created?

Comment: All of the elements of `ptrs` are pointers, and all point at the SAME `node` which is also pointed to be `temp`.   So the last loop prints `temp->x` ten times.     Generally speaking, copying a pointer does not copy or clone the object that pointer points at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating only 1 `node` object and then storing 10 `node*` pointers into your vector that all point at that 1 `node` object.  So, in your 1st loop, all of the assignments to `x` are on that 1 `node`.  When that 1st loop is finished, whatever last value was assigned to the 1 `node`'s `x`, that is what your 2nd loop prints out 10 times.

For what you are attempting, you need to allocate and free 10 separate `node` objects, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
struct node{
    int x;
};
node* temp;
std::vector<node*> ptrs;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    temp = new node; // <-- MOVED HERE!!!
    temp->x = i;
    ptrs.push_back(temp);
}
std::vector<node*>::iterator j;
for (j = ptrs.begin(); j != ptrs.end(); ++j){
    std::cout << (*j)->x;
}
for (j = ptrs.begin(); j != ptrs.end(); ++j){ // <-- ADD THIS LOOP!!!
    temp = *j;
    delete temp;
}
```

But, why are you using pointers at all?  This is not a good example that warrants the use of pointers at all.  You should create a `vector` of `node` objects, not a `vector` of pointers to `node` objects, eg:

```cpp
#include <vector>
struct node{
    int x;
};
std::vector<node> nodes;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    node temp;
    temp.x = i;
    nodes.push_back(temp);
}
std::vector<node>::iterator j;
for (j = nodes.begin(); j != nodes.end(); ++j){
    std::cout << j->x; // or (*j).x
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <vector>
struct node{
    int x;
};
std::vector<node> nodes(10);
std::vector<node>::iterator j;
for (j = nodes.begin(); j != nodes.end(); ++j){
    j->x = i; // or (*j).x
}
for (j = nodes.begin(); j != nodes.end(); ++j){
    std::cout << j->x; // or (*j).x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to declare the function main. Outside any function you may use only declarations. So at least this part of the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    temp->x = i;
    ptrs.push_back(temp);
}
std::vector<node*>:: iterator j;
for (j = ptrs.begin(); j != ptrs.end(); j++){
    std::cout << (*j)->x;
}
delete temp;
```

must be placed in a function.

This loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    temp->x = i;
    ptrs.push_back(temp);
}
```

places the same pointer in the vector. So this statement

```
    temp->x = i;
```

changes the data member `x` of the same object pointed to by the same pointer `temp` the copy of which is pushed in the vector. That is after this loop all elements of the vector will point to the same one dynamically allocated object.

You need to create a new object of the type node for each value `i`.

The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct node{
    int x;
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>> ptrs;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        ptrs.emplace_back( new node { i } );
    }

    for ( const auto &p : ptrs )
    {
        std::cout << p->x << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Using the smart pointer `unique_ptr` allows you not to bother about deleting the allocated memory.